# Issue in Changing EditText background after setting error to the TextInputLayout on Android M

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I have set custom background to the EditText in Xml file. After validation, i am setting different background to EditText at runtime and also setting error to TextInputLayout. But in Android M instead of setting background resource, it is setting background color to EditText.

[This is image before setting error to the TextInputLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP7WF.jpg)

[This is the image after setting error to the TextInputLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys38W.png)

Below is my code:-

**XML file code**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
app:errorTextAppearance="@style/ErrorText">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_selector"
    android:hint="@string/hint_name"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**Validation code**

```
if (inputName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
    inputLayoutName.setErrorEnabled(true);
    inputLayoutName.setError("Errorrroror");
    inputName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext_red_focused);
    requestFocus(inputName);
    return false;
} else {
    inputName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext_selector);
    inputLayoutName.setErrorEnabled(false);
}

return true;
```

**Below is my resource file for error**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
<shape>
<solid android:color="@color/sale_color" />
</shape>
</item>

<!-- main color -->
<item
android:bottom="1.0dp"
android:left="1.0dp"
android:right="1.0dp">
<shape>
<solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
</item>

<!-- draw another block to cut-off the left and right bars -->
<item android:bottom="1.0dp">
<shape>
<solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this using custom Edittext background.

Create selector drawable like below,

Then,

**edittext_normal.xml**

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:left="-2dp"
    android:right="-2dp"
    android:top="-2dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/edit_text_normal_color" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

**edittext_focused.xml**

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:left="-2dp"
    android:right="-2dp"
    android:top="-2dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

**edittext_red_focused.xml**

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:left="-2dp"
    android:right="-2dp"
    android:top="-2dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/sale_color" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

And set the error drawable at runtime, when error occurs

**Validation Code**

```
private boolean validateName() {

    if (inputName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        inputLayoutName.setErrorEnabled(true);
        inputLayoutName.setError("Error");
        inputName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext_red_focused);
        return false;
    } else {
        inputName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext_selector);
        inputLayoutName.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but i need bottom line in my editText background and this resource file display blank background.

Comment: For focused mode, you could simply put the item in the same file with `android:state_focused="true"`