# Custom TextInputLayout's error BACKGROUND color

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to change `TextInputLayout` error BACKGROUND color, not the text one from transparent to red for example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063847/issue-in-changing-edittext-background-after-setting-error-to-the-textinputlayout it should help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically set TextInputLayout Hint Text Color and Floating Label Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35683379/programmatically-set-textinputlayout-hint-text-color-and-floating-label-color)

Answer (score 0):

**Create style in style.xml**

```
<style name="error_appearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red_500</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

**And use it in your TextInputLayout widget:**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/emailInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance">
```

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem. I want change background color, not text color.

Answer (score 0):

Add latest material dependecies in gradle and use **setError**

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'

emailInputLayout =(TextInputLayout)findViewbyId(R.id.emailInputLayout);
Spannable errorMsg = new SpannableString("Email cannot be Empty ");

errorMsg.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, errorMsg.length(), 
 Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
errorMsg.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), 0, errorMsg.length(), 
 Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

emailInputLayout.setError(errorMsg);
```

This works fine.

Comment: I want to change background color of error field. How does it helps me? :D

Comment: after catching the error programatically set the value of edit text background .